# how to specify which filter is selected - react - material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

i am making a blog with filter, the filtering just works fine but I want to specify which the filter is selected..

the code is

```js
{cardCategories.map((cat) => {
  return (
    <Chip
      key={cat}
      style={{ margin: "5px 5px 25px 5px" }}
      label={cat}
      variant='outlined'
      clickable
      id={cat}
      onClick={handleCategoryChange}
    />
  );
})}
```

this show the following

[image]

when clicked one of these button the filtered posts are shown below this but we can't figure out which category is selected. This chip component is made with material-ui.

I want to apply styling on the clicked button so that is shows which of the categories is selected. If I apply styling with

```
document.getElementById("All").style.border = "1px solid red"
```

then it is applied but when clicked on the 2nd category it then shows styling on the both and so it does not remove the border from the previous but applies on all the clicked ones.

[image]

Comment: `Chip` components don't have any "active" or "selected" state so you may need to play with custom styling and available props like `color` to highlight what chip is "selected". Can you share more of your code, how filters are selected, etc...?

Comment: As Drew said., you need to  conditionally style it. You can do something like this: <Chip className={cat === selectedCategory? styles.selected: null} ...>...

Comment: If I apply styling with
----
document.getElementById("All").style.border = "1px solid red"----
then it is applied but when clicked on the 2nd category it then shows styling on the both and so it does not remove the border from the previous but applies on all the clicked ones.

Comment: That's why you don't mutate the DOM in React! Use the `style` prop or `className` where valid. If you are manually adding style directly to the DOM then you need to manually remove it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
 {cardCategories.map((cat) => {
        return (
          <Chip
            key={cat}
            style={{ margin: "5px 5px 25px 5px" }}
            className={cat === currentCategory ? classes.selectedCAT : null}
            label={cat}
            variant='outlined'
            clickable
            id={cat}
            onClick={handleCategoryChange}
          />
        );
      })}
```

By Adding className styling worked fine